# FileNotFoundException on accessing assets files

Tags: java, android, file, exception, copy

I'm trying to copy a file from assets folder to my app's internal files directory but it keeps throwing FileNotFoundException

j

```
ava.io.FileNotFoundException: android.content.res.AssetManager@f252431/wordsdb.ser: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.829 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.829 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.829 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at stickyapps.zabanamooz.Managers.WordsManager.copy(WordsManager.java:91)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.830 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at stickyapps.zabanamooz.Managers.WordsManager.<init>(WordsManager.java:46)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.830 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at stickyapps.zabanamooz.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:40)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.830 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7802)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.830 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7791)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.830 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1299)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.831 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3245)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.831 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3409)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.831 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.831 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.831 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.831 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.831 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.832 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.832 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.832 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.832 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.833 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.836 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err: Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
2020-04-05 19:44:48.836 11247-11247/stickyapps.zabanamooz W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Linux.open(Native Method)
```

...

I'm using this code:

```
        File file1 = new File(context.getAssets() + "/wordsdb.ser");
        File file2 = new File(context.getFilesDir() + "/wordsdb.ser");

        try {
            copy(file1,file2);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

copy method:

```
public void copy(File src, File dst) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream in = new FileInputStream(src)) {
        try (OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(dst)) {
            // Transfer bytes from in to out
            byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
            int len;
            while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) {
                out.write(buf, 0, len);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried restarting android studio, rebuilding project, reinstalling app and ... 
but still no luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using asset manager

```
AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
String[] files = assetManager.list("");
```

This to open a certian file:

```
InputStream input = assetManager.open(assetName);
```

Comment: Thank you. The solution was using AssetManager :)

Comment: Happy to hep you :-)

Comment: @DeepakSingh can you please help me in this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76734900/how-to-copy-and-upload-file-with-tar-gz-extension-from-asset-folder-in-android