# How to copy and upload file with .tar.gz extension from asset folder in android

Tags: android

I kept R2.tar.gz file in asset folder in android project but when i try to read this file i  am getting file not found exception . i am using below code to read file from asset folder .

```
@Throws(IOException::class)
    private fun copydatabase(fileName: String) {
        // Open your local db as the input stream
        val myinput: InputStream = assetManager.open("file:///android_asset/"+fileName)
        val buffStream = BufferedInputStream(myinput)
        val zis = GZIPInputStream(buffStream)

        // Path to the just created empty db
        val outfilename: String = ""

        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        val myoutput: OutputStream = FileOutputStream(outfilename)


        // transfer byte to inputfile to outputfile
        val buffer = ByteArray(1024)
        var length: Int
        while (zis.read(buffer).also { length = it } > 0) {
            myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length)
        }

        // Close the streams
        myoutput.flush()
        myoutput.close()
        zis.close()
        buffStream.close()
        myinput.close()
    }
```

can any one help me how to read file from asset folder in android
[image]

Comment: The extension or type of a file does not matter if you want to copy that file or upload it. One code fits all. So you dont need a gzipninputstream to begin with. A gzipninputstream is only needed if you wantvto unzip the file. Your question should be simplified to: how to copy a file from assets?

Comment: @blackapps thanks  for responding  yeas i want to upload file but i tried to read file .tar,gz using assetmanager code its giving exception file not found

Comment: 'assetManager.open("file:///android_asset/"+fileName)' That should be 'assetManager.open(fileName)'

Comment: FileOutputStream("") is nonsense.

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/3czczodc this my code i am trying to upload file http that i send for sample @blackapps

Comment: Please dont talk about upload yet. First handle the copy.

Comment: ok so i tried again when i give file name R2.tar.gz then its showing exception file not found exception but when i give R.tar then i am able to upload file but its not extracting in our server

Comment: Your code is about copying. It has nothing to do with uploading.

Comment: I have just found the solution android not recognising .tar.gz its recognising only .tar using .tar i am able to upload file its worked